# Get parent element of iframe if iframe src is cross domain

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

i have simple html webpage, guess main page domain is **mainDomain.com** .
This webpage contain `<iframe id="a1" src="http://crossdomain.com/page1.htm">` tag and this `<iframe>` tag src is cross domain.
The `<iframe id="a1" src="http://crossdomain.com/page1.htm">` contain one more `<iframe>` tag and thats src `<iframe id="a1" src="http://mainDomain.com/page2.html">`

I want to get content of`<iframe id="a1" src="http://crossdomain.com/page1.htm">`, using main page or `<iframe id="frame2">`.
please help me ,how can i do this?

```html
<!doctype>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<h1>hello world</h1>
<iframe src="http://crossdomain.com/page1.htm"  id="frame1">         
     <h2 id="hader1" > hey dad </h2>            
        <iframe src="http://mainDomain.com/page2.html" id="frame2">
          <p>this is second frame</p>
        </iframe>            
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No cross-domain access, unless you can [control the other domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).

Comment: i want to do this any way , please suggest me a way

Comment: [You simply can't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) with JS.

Comment: Use a server and something like cURL to download the content on the server. That's about the extent, the browser won't give you access in the browser, unless you author a browser extension.

Answer (score -1):

If i understant your question corrcectly , you wanna get contents from `<iframe id="frame2">` into `<iframe id="frame1">`.

and i deem that JQuery is useful way to get contents as cross-domain access.

```
<script>
$('#frame1').load(function(){
    $('#frame').contents().find('#hader1').text();
});
</script>
```